# UWP ListView x:Bind SelectionMode StackoOverflowException

Tags: listview, mvvm, uwp, stack-overflow

I have a ListView and I want to change the SelectionMode in a ViewModel. That works half. It works that I click a button and the SelectionMode changes between Single and Multiple. But if I have a selected item in the ListView and change to Multiple than I get a StackOverflowException at this Point in the MainPage.g.cs:

```
public static void Set_Windows_UI_Xaml_Controls_ListViewBase_SelectionMode(global::Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.ListViewBase obj, global::Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.ListViewSelectionMode value)
        {
            obj.SelectionMode = value; //<--- here is the error
        }
```

Here is my ListView:

```
<ListView x:Name="MyList" Grid.Row="2" ItemsSource="{x:Bind ViewModel.Threads, Mode=OneWay}" SelectedItem="{x:Bind ViewModel.Selected, Mode=TwoWay}" ShowsScrollingPlaceholders="True" SelectionMode="{x:Bind ViewModel.ListSelectionMode, Mode=OneWay}">
                <interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
                    <core:EventTriggerBehavior EventName="SelectionChanged">
                        <core:InvokeCommandAction Command="{x:Bind ViewModel.SelectionChangedCommand}"
                                  InputConverter="{StaticResource SelectionChangedConverter}"
                                  InputConverterParameter="{Binding ElementName=MyList}" />
                    </core:EventTriggerBehavior>
                </interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
</ListView>
```

Here the ViewModel:

```
private ListViewSelectionMode _listSelectionMode = ListViewSelectionMode.Single;
    public ListViewSelectionMode ListSelectionMode
    {
        get { return _listSelectionMode; }
        set
        {
            if (_listSelectionMode != value)
            {
                _listSelectionMode = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }

    private List<object> _selectedThreads = new List<object>();
    public List<object> SelectedThreads
    {
        get { return _selectedThreads; }
        set
        {
            if (value != _selectedThreads)
            {
                _selectedThreads = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }

    private string _selectedThreadCounter;
    public string SelectedThreadCounter
    {
        get { return _selectedThreadCounter; }
        set
        {
            if (value != _selectedThreadCounter)
            {
                _selectedThreadCounter = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }

private RelayCommand<IList<object>> _selectionChangedCommand;
    public RelayCommand<IList<object>> SelectionChangedCommand
    {
        get
        {
            if (_selectionChangedCommand == null && ListSelectionMode == ListViewSelectionMode.Multiple)
            {
                _selectionChangedCommand = new RelayCommand<IList<object>>(
                    items =>
                    {
                        SelectedThreads = items.ToList();
                        SelectedThreadCounter = "(" + SelectedThreads.Count + ")";
                    }
                );
            }

            return _selectionChangedCommand;
        }
    }
```

Here is the SelectionChangedConverter:

```
public class SelectionChangedConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        var listView = parameter as ListView;

        return listView.SelectedItems;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

I hope that is enough Code to help for finding the answer.

**UPDATE:**
Maybe I should add that my ItemsSource Looks like this in the ViewModel:

```
private IRealmCollection<ThreadRealm> _threads;
    public IRealmCollection<ThreadRealm> Threads
    {
        get { return _threads; }
        set
        {
            if (_threads != value)
            {
                _threads = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }
```

it is IRealmCollection from [Realm](https://realm.io/) database

Comment: I got the `StackoOverflowException` at the `RaisePropertyChanged` in `Selected` property.

Comment: When I change the x:Bind to Binding than I also get the exception at the RaisePropertyChanged. But why? Or what could I do to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

According to your description and code snippet, I made a code sample to test. It worked well on my side.

Please check the following code:

```xml
<Page.Resources>
    <local:SelectionChangedConverter x:Key="SelectionChangedConverter"></local:SelectionChangedConverter>
</Page.Resources>

<Grid>
    <ListView x:Name="MyList" Grid.Row="2" ItemsSource="{x:Bind ViewModel.Threads,Mode=OneWay}" SelectedItem="{x:Bind ViewModel.Selected,Mode=TwoWay}" ShowsScrollingPlaceholders="True" SelectionMode="{x:Bind ViewModel.ListSelectionMode,Mode=OneWay}">
        <interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
            <core:EventTriggerBehavior EventName="SelectionChanged">
                <core:InvokeCommandAction Command="{x:Bind ViewModel.SelectionChangedCommand}"
                              InputConverter="{StaticResource SelectionChangedConverter}"
                              InputConverterParameter="{Binding ElementName=MyList}" />
            </core:EventTriggerBehavior>
        </interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
    </ListView>

    <Button Content="switch" Click="Button_Click"></Button>
</Grid>
```

```cs
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    private ViewModel _viewModel;

    public ViewModel ViewModel { get => _viewModel; set => _viewModel = value; }
    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        ViewModel = new ViewModel();
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ViewModel.ListSelectionMode = MyList.SelectionMode==ListViewSelectionMode.Multiple?ListViewSelectionMode.Single:ListViewSelectionMode.Multiple;
    }
}
```

```cs
public class ViewModel:ViewModelBase
{
    private ListViewSelectionMode _listSelectionMode = ListViewSelectionMode.Single;
    public ListViewSelectionMode ListSelectionMode
    {
        get { return _listSelectionMode; }
        set
        {
            if (_listSelectionMode != value)
            {
                _listSelectionMode = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }

    private List<object> _selectedThreads = new List<object>();
    public List<object> SelectedThreads
    {
        get { return _selectedThreads; }
        set
        {
            if (value != _selectedThreads)
            {
                _selectedThreads = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }

    private string _selectedThreadCounter;
    public string SelectedThreadCounter
    {
        get { return _selectedThreadCounter; }
        set
        {
            if (value != _selectedThreadCounter)
            {
                _selectedThreadCounter = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }

    private RelayCommand<IList<object>> _selectionChangedCommand;
    public RelayCommand<IList<object>> SelectionChangedCommand
    {
        get
        {
            if (_selectionChangedCommand == null && ListSelectionMode == ListViewSelectionMode.Multiple)
            {
                _selectionChangedCommand = new RelayCommand<IList<object>>(
                    items =>
                    {
                        SelectedThreads = items.ToList();
                        SelectedThreadCounter = "(" + SelectedThreads?.Count + ")";
                    }
                );
            }

            return _selectionChangedCommand;
        }
    }


    private ObservableCollection<string> _Threads;
    public ObservableCollection<string> Threads
    {
        get { return _Threads; }
        set
        {
            _Threads = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    private string _Selected;
    public string Selected
    {
        get { return _Selected; }
        set
        {
            if (this._Selected != value)
            {
                _Selected = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }

    public ViewModel()
    {
        Threads = new ObservableCollection<string>();
        Threads.Add("1");
        Threads.Add("2");
        Threads.Add("3");
    }
}
```

```cs
public class SelectionChangedConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        var listView = parameter as ListView;

        return listView.SelectedItems;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Comment: I checked it and it crashes. Is it also possible for you to select an item in the list and than switch the SelectionMode? Please at my updated question

Comment: @newone `Is it also possible for you to select an item in the list and than switch the SelectionMode? ` Yes. My code sample worked well. I've checked your updated code, it still was incomplete. Please upload a simple reproducible code sample and post link here. Then, I will test your sample on my side and diagnose this issue.

Comment: I created a test project. You can download it from [here](https://1drv.ms/u/s!Ak_wyPzlftH_l_xE-FqXwtsa6-ONeg) The steps to reproduce are in the App thanks and I hope it helps.

Comment: @newone I cannot build your project successfully. There're many errors. See [Screenshot1](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AoI4pKdRYn8KnG_EPB-ym9n9ibXq) and [Screenshot2](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AoI4pKdRYn8KnHFJpdxo3Aa68j3E). Could you please provide a simple reproducible code sample?

Comment: Have you tried clean and rebuild? It worked on my site on different PCs. The Project was also build with the 'Windows Template Studio'.

Comment: @newone Yes. I've tried to clean and rebuild it, but unsuccessfully. You could see my above screenshots, there're many exclamation marks in references. Please remove the irrelevant libraries and just provide a simplest code sample.

Comment: [Here](https://1drv.ms/u/s!Ak_wyPzlftH_l_x-LkNseVLKyyJ__g) is a new, small and simple Project. Hope it works now :-)

Comment: Is it possible for you to run the new project?